# How to Print spyder console tab name?

Tags: python, spyder

I just want to save the spyder console tab name into a text file.

```
from spyder_kernels.customize.spydercustomize import get_spyder_python_path

# Get the console name and ID
console_name = get_spyder_python_path()
console_id = id(console_name)

print(f"Console Name: {console_name}")
print(f"Console ID: {console_id}")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.